# Vue JS: Prop's property change is not detected inside sub-components

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a simple media player app. This is the simplified app structure:

```
|-- app.vue
|-- components
|   |-- main-wrapper
|   |   |-- index.vue
|   |   |-- main-content
|   |   |   |-- albums.vue
|   |   |   |-- artists.vue
|   |   |   |-- index.vue
|   |   |   |-- songs.vue
|   |   `-- sidebar
|   |       `-- playlists.vue
|   |-- shared
|       `-- song-item.vue
`-- main.js
```

The song list is fetched from the top level `app.vue` and subsequently passed down as `props` to `components/main-wrapper/index.vue`,  `components/main-wrapper/main/content/index.vue`, and `components/main-wrapper/main/content/songs.vue`, in that order. All `props` are defined as dynamic – e.g. `:list="songs"` – and registered in the child components – e.g. `props: ['list']` and such.

Now in the `songs.vue` subcomponent I have this code:

```
<template>
    <tbody>
        <tr is="song-item" v-for="song in list" track-by="id" :song="song"></tr>
    </tbody>
</template>

<script>
    import songItem from '../../shared/song-item.vue';

    export default {
        props: ['list'], // register the prop from parent, as said above
        replace: false,
        components: { songItem }
    };
</script>
```

Each `songItem` is a component instance (?) that has its own status set by checking `song.playing`, i.e. to highlight the text if it's being played.

```
<style>.playing { color: #f00; }</style>

<template>
    <tr :class="{ 'playing': song.playing }">
        <td class="title">{{ song.title }}</td>
        <td class="controls">
            <i v-show="!song.playing" class="fa fa-play-circle" @click="play"></i>
            <i v-show="song.playing" class="fa fa-pause-circle" @click="pause"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['song'], // again, register the prop from parent

        methods: {
            play() {
                this.$root.play(this.song);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, `this.$root.play(this.song)` will set the current song's `playing` property to `false`, replace it with the newly provided `this.song` parameter, and set this new song's `playing` to `true`.

With this approach, I'd expect that every time a new song is played, its component's `<tr>` will be highlighted with `.playing` class activated, when those of others will be dimmed due to `.playing` class removed. Sadly, it's not the case. Apparently the songs' `playing` property is not watched at all, so even though it's changed in every `Song` object, the CSS class is never toggled.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure if a simple fiddle can handle this. As mentioned above, this is a simplified (very simplified) version of the app, which actually has ~50 files now, and has a PHP backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a property (like `playingSong`) to the `app.vue` and pass it as [synced property](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop_Binding_Types) to the `song-item` template.

Then, instead of `this.$root.play(this.song)`, you should set `this.playingSong = this.song`

And then, create a computed property to check the song

```
computed: {
    playing() {
        return this.playingSong === this.song
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works, even though a bit tidious – is there a better way than passing the `currentSong` all around like this?

Comment: Maybe you could access it like this `this.$root.playingSong`

Comment: Right, I'll try this. Thanks!